# C# attach listener to a Npgsql connection

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm building an app in C# that use npgsql connection for queries in postgres database. I want to know if there is a way to be notified at all steps of query execution; 
I mean i want to receive messages :

- "open" : when connection is open
- "connecting" : when connection is connecting
- "executing" : when connection is executing
- "close" : when query is executed and connection closed

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you have to trigger the notifications yourself. It is doable and even easy. In ADO.NET you have code flow similar to:

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Npgsql");
using(DbConnection con = factory.CreateConnection()) 
{
      con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[connectionName];
      con.Open();  
      // Connection is open, notify user
      DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = query; 

      // Query execution is going to start, add code to inform user
      cmd.ExecuteXXX();
      // Query execution is done, add code to inform user
}

// the connection is closed - notify user
```

Notifications should be asynchronous to avoid blocking the database code you can implement them with events.

Comment: thanks you @devdimi, but i don't find enough doc to how implement an event

Comment: that would be another question :)
explaining the event mechanism in C# would to too much long  for a short comment.
For starters you don't have to use them, first make the code work without events  and notifications. Than you can add notifications object that provides methods for them and call e.g. notifier.ConnectionOpenNotification()
When that works you can change the implementation of these notifications to use events or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to trap the `StateChange` event? Hope this will point you at the right direction.

```
    Dim csb = New NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(GetConnectionString(connectionName))
    csb.CommandTimeout = 0
    Using connection = New NpgsqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString)
        AddHandler connection.StateChange, AddressOf myHandler  ' <== This is where you specify the event Handler
        Using transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
            ' Do your thing here.
            transaction.Commit()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub


' This function will get called whenever the connection state changes.
Private Function myHandler(sender As Object, e As StateChangeEventArgs) As Object
    ' Do something here
End Function
```

Comment: StateChange notify me only "closed" and "open" state, i want a notification at each step of request execution

Comment: The same principle applies. You can trap/handle the event of the SqlCommand.OnStatementCompleted. basically, you can write a wrapper class to handle both the ExecuteQuery() and the OnStatementCompletion event.